# JS: Decode, Filter and Re-Append Escaped XML File

Tags: javascript, html, xml, import, filter

One of the websites I frequent has their entire TV schedule escaped/encoded inside of a `<script>` which sits as the first item inside the `<head>`. They do not have an RSS feed for this schedule which is why I'm always checking it. The first portion of this insanely long code is as follows:

```
txt = '%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cchannel_guide%20operating-unit...
```

The whole thing is a giant `XML` file. After viewing the unescaped bits inside of my local text editor, I come to find that my favorite shows each have their own unique 5-digit series ID number. Additionally, I also discover that the `HTML` of the entire schedule is built dynamically.

Inside the unescaped `XML`, the code block for an episode is as follows:

```
<episode code="1336454" recording_type="">
<title>NAME OF EPISODE</title>
<description></description>
<series id="12345"/>
<content-rating>Ratings N/A</content-rating>
<duration minutes="120"/>
<show-time premiere_type="" live="Repeat">
<eastern hour="22" minute="00"/>
<mexico-city hour="21" minute="00"/>
<buenos-aries hour="00" minute="00"/>
</show-time>
</episode>
```

What I want to do is...

1. Filter just the shows I want using their unique series ID.
2. Export the **date**, **time**, **series name** (mapped via series ID), and **episode name** into a `<table>` on my website--currently using Joomla 2.5 as CMS.

If anyone could give me any advice on where to begin or how to achieve this I'd very much appreciate it. I'm currently experimenting with *Scriptish* (Firefox) and *TamperMonkey* (Chrome) to write local scripts when trying to achieve this task.

---

**EDIT 9 Oct. 2013:** I've successfully made a Y! Pipe that retrieves the `txt` from the external website and imports it into an `XML` `<title>` element. The `XML` source can be viewed here: `view-source:http://bit.ly/1e7O5pS` (copy & paste in address bar to go directly to raw text). Another thing I forgot to mention earlier, the external website has its own XML decoder script. The decoder source can be viewed on Pastebin here: http://bit.ly/GNdeKu. Now that I'm able to retrieve the information, my next question is how can I utilize the external site's XML decoder and incorporate my filters into it while on my website? Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

**EDIT 9 Oct. 2013:** I've made some huge progress over the last few hours. Here's the Grease/TamperMonkey script I've written as a local tester:

```
var showID = {
  61189 : 'Show 1',
  61190 : 'Show 2',
  61393 : 'Show 3',
  61395 : 'Show 4',
  60486 : 'Show 5',
  68253 : 'Show 6'
}

var k = Object.keys(showID);
var n = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(showID);
GM_log(k);

function loadXMLString(txt) {
  if(window.DOMParser) {
    parser=new DOMParser();
    xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(txt,"text/xml");
  }
  else {
    xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
    xmlDoc.async=false;
    xmlDoc.loadXML(txt); 
  }
  return xmlDoc;
}

if(xmlDoc != 'undefined') {
  GM_log(xmlDoc);
  var shows = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('series');
  GM_log(shows);
  $(shows).each(function() {
    var myShows = $.grep(this.id.split(' '), function(value) {
      return k.indexOf(value) > -1;
    })[0];
  });
}
```

This issue I'm running into is that in the console, all of the shows are showing up instead of just the ones with the specific `showID`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function toDOM(xmlStr) {
  var container = document.createElement("DIV");

  // feel free to remove the XML declaration here
  // replacing /<\?xml.*?\?>/ with the empty string
  container.innerHTML = str;
  return container.firstChild;
}
```

and

```
var txt = '%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22iso-8859-1%22%3F%3E%0A%3Cchannel_guide%20operating-unit...';

var dom = toDOM(decodeURIComponent(txt))

var series = dom.querySelectorAll("series[id='12345']")
var episode = series.parentNode;

// and so on
```

Notes

- Of course this parses your XML with the browser's HTML parser, but unless the XML is very complex (ie, using namespaces and or something like that) you should be fine.
- `querySelectorAll()` is not available on older platforms. Compare http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll

Comment: Thank you for answering. I keep getting _URIError: URI Malformed_ in the console. Thankfully, `unescape(txt)` works. I'm still a little lost on why I need to remove XML declaration. Please clarify.

Comment: Because it might confuse the browser's parser, it's just a cautionary measure. You can leave it alone, browsers *should* ignore it.

Comment: PS: Of course you can use whatever XML parsing facility your platform offers, but I'm not sure if there's consistent XML support across platforms. Using the HTML parser to deal with the content might be easier than the alternatives, for trivial XML like your's in any case.

Comment: Here's the actual schedule I'm referring to: http://is.gd/8Q5CWK. The `txt` is in the first `<script>` element in the `<head>`. Thoughts?

Comment: So what are you currently doing to retrieve this page? Also, have you thought about using their `tvfeed.js` to parse and handle the XML? Maybe it's not necessary to roll your own parser in the first place.

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do--use the tvfeed.js--but this is where I hit the wall in terms of how to actually utilize it on my site while integrating my filter for specific items. I'm a designer who's becoming a programmer. Still a novice but determined to master JS, PHP, Python, Ruby, Perl, and C#.

Comment: I see... I don't think it's useful to solve the entire problem here in the comments or in this question thread. That would become too broad and complex which means it's less likely to help anyone besides yourself. Maybe it's better if you split up the problem and come back with more questions if you can't solve specific things.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38850/discussion-between-daveyjake-and-tomalak)